# Downloading data from a number of urls in background thread using NSOperationQueue synchronously

Tags: objective-c, synchronous, nsoperationqueue

I need to download data from a number of urls synchronously which needs to be done in the background thread so that it won't affect the front end activities.I would like to use NSOpeartionQueue and NSURLSession. Right now I am using the below code.

```
 for (int i=0;i<[tempArray count];i++) {
            CheckList * checklist = (CheckList *)[tempArray objectAtIndex:i];

        [operationQueue addOperationWithBlock:^{

            dispatch_semaphore_t semaphore = dispatch_semaphore_create(0);

            NSString * urlStr = [[BASE_URL stringByAppendingString:DOWNLOAD_CHECKLIST_METADATA_SUBURL] stringByAppendingFormat:@"%@/%d/%@",userName,[checklist.checklistId intValue],checklist.language];
            NSURL * url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlStr];
            NSLog(@"url is %@",url);

            NSURLSessionConfiguration *config = [NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration];
            NSURLSession *session = [NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration:config];

            NSMutableURLRequest * request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:url];
            [request setTimeoutInterval:240.0];
            [request setValue:@"Application/JSON" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
            NSURLSessionDataTask * downloadTask =[session dataTaskWithRequest:request completionHandler:^(NSData * data, NSURLResponse * response, NSError * error)
                                                  {

                                                      NSString * str = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
                                                      NSLog(@"response is %@",str);
                                                  }];
            [downloadTask resume];
            [indexSetBg addIndex:[checklist.checklistId intValue]];
            // but have the thread wait until the task is done

            dispatch_semaphore_wait(semaphore, DISPATCH_TIME_FOREVER);


        }];

        }
```

But if I want to send the request synchronously, is there any way for that.Means after getting 1st response ,second request needs to be sent. Can anyone of you please help me to accomplish this.

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: What is your actual issue? That you want to continue doing stuff after all downloads are finished or that you do not want to start a download, before the previous finished?

Answer (score 0):

you need to add  dispatch_semaphore_signal(semaphore);

in the end of  your NSURLSessionTask completion handler

```
  for (int i=0;i<[tempArray count];i++) {
        CheckList * checklist = (CheckList *)[tempArray objectAtIndex:i];

    [operationQueue addOperationWithBlock:^{

        dispatch_semaphore_t semaphore = dispatch_semaphore_create(0);

        NSString * urlStr = [[BASE_URL stringByAppendingString:DOWNLOAD_CHECKLIST_METADATA_SUBURL] stringByAppendingFormat:@"%@/%d/%@",userName,[checklist.checklistId intValue],checklist.language];
        NSURL * url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlStr];
        NSLog(@"url is %@",url);

        NSURLSessionConfiguration *config = [NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration];
        NSURLSession *session = [NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration:config];

        NSMutableURLRequest * request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:url];
        [request setTimeoutInterval:240.0];
        [request setValue:@"Application/JSON" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
        NSURLSessionDataTask * downloadTask =[session dataTaskWithRequest:request completionHandler:^(NSData * data, NSURLResponse * response, NSError * error)
                                              {

                                                  NSString * str = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
                                                  NSLog(@"response is %@",str);
                                                  dispatch_semaphore_signal(semaphore);
                                              }];
        [downloadTask resume];
        [indexSetBg addIndex:[checklist.checklistId intValue]];
        // but have the thread wait until the task is done

        dispatch_semaphore_wait(semaphore, DISPATCH_TIME_FOREVER);


    }];

    }
```

Comment: My problem here is downloading is happening one by one. But all requests are being sent almost together. So in a second or two all the requests would be sent. So by the time I click on download button, request for that particular url might have sent.

Comment: on your button click event you can check the tasks of you NSURLSession with  getTasksWithCompletionHandler , for each data task , check its url ,see if it is qual to the url of the task that should be fired on button click, if yes you do nothing if no you can download with task you create in you click event and disable the operation. for doing it you should hold a dictionary of url (as key) and operation as value so you will be able to disable the operation, for preventing duplicate downloads

Comment: see this example  of getTaskWithCompletionHandler here :https://gist.github.com/sudeepjaiswal/4ed79ac947e4776d4aed

Comment: :Can you please help me with the code to compare the operations and to store the operations in NSMutableDictionary

Comment: I don't understand how I can add the operation as value to NSMUtableDictionary . Could you please help me with this.

Comment: [dictionary addObject:<your operation> forKey:<url string>];

Comment: How too get the operation object from within that block?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/131053/discussion-between-iosmaniac-and-marat-ibragimov).